# Escaping special characters with sh -c

Tags: bash

When I run the following command from shell, it works fine:

```
# ./testdollar.py 1 2 '"source"="Zabbix"|| "name"="testlog trigger"|| "trigger_name"="*UNKNOWN*"|| "trigger_group"="Zabbix servers"|| "trigger_description"=""|| "id"="291058"|| "item_name"="Testlog"|| "item_value"="HFD3D$01"|| "item_lastvalue"="HFD3D$01"|| "reference_url"="http://test"|| "status_open"="1"|| "hostname"="Zabbix server"||
"ip"="10.10.10.1"|| "value"="1"|| "event_id"="62510700"|| "severity"="Not classified"||
"datetime_item_cst"="1969.12.31 18:00:00"|| "datetime_cst"="2016.10.07 03:59:08"|| "sourceid"="62510700"'
```

But I need to run it as:

sh -c "the whole command with arguments"

I've tried this:

```
sh -c /data/zabbix/share/zabbix/alertscripts/testdollar.py 1 2 '"source"="Zabbix"|| "name"="testlog trigger"|| "trigger_name"="*UNKNOWN*"|| "trigger_group"="Zabbix servers"|| "trigger_description"=""|| "id"="291058"|| "item_name"="Testlog"|| "item_value"="HFD3D$01"|| "item_lastvalue"="HFD3D$01"|| "reference_url"="http://test"|| "status_open"="1"|| "hostname"="Zabbix server"||
"ip"="10.10.10.1"|| "value"="1"|| "event_id"="62510700"|| "severity"="Not classified"||
"datetime_item_cst"="1969.12.31 18:00:00"|| "datetime_cst"="2016.10.07 03:59:08"|| "sourceid"="62510700"'
```

Gives the following error, which indicates that it could not read the third argument that includes a lot of quotes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/zabbix/share/zabbix/alertscripts/testdollar.py", line 3, in <module>
    data=sys.argv[3]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Tried this:

```
sh -c '/data/zabbix/share/zabbix/alertscripts/testdollar.py 1 2 "source"="Zabbix"|| "name"="testlog trigger"|| "trigger_name"="*UNKNOWN*"|| "trigger_group"="Zabbix servers"|| "trigger_description"=""|| "id"="291058"|| "item_name"="Testlog"|| "item_value"="HFD3D$01"|| "item_lastvalue"="HFD3D$01"|| "reference_url"="http://test"|| "status_open"="1"|| "hostname"="Zabbix server"||
"ip"="10.10.10.1"|| "value"="1"|| "event_id"="62510700"|| "severity"="Not classified"||
"datetime_item_cst"="1969.12.31 18:00:00"|| "datetime_cst"="2016.10.07 03:59:08"|| "sourceid"="62510700"'
```

Which run OK but when I check the outcome of the command, I can see that it stopped reading the third argument just after "source"="Zabbix"|| part. Same thing happens if I wrap the whole thing with double quotes instead of single quotes.

Tried with other combinations of single and double quotes but could not figure it out. Do I need to escape special characters in the command argument? If so, how?

EDIT:

Easier way to test:

```
sh -c 'echo '"A=x"||"B=y"||"C=z"''
A=x
```

Comment: Try to enclose your multiline argument between triple-quotes, '''like this'''

Comment: Tried: sh -c 'command 1 2 '''long argument'''' and sh -c "command 1 2 '''long argument'''" same thing happens.

Comment: `sh -c $'testdollar.py 1 2 \'"A"||"B"||"C"\''`

Comment: that works but is there any way to make it work without that dollar sign at the beginning?

Comment: No the dollar sign is why it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use double quotes around the whole command and then escape double quotes within the command string:

```
sh -c "echo '\"A=x\"||\"B=y\"||\"C=z\"'"
```

Remember that parameters will be expanded within double quotes, so if you have any `$` in your string, then you will need to escape them `\$`.

The alternative isn't particularly appealing:

```
sh -c 'echo '"'"'"A=x"||"B=y"||"C=z"'"'"''
```

To use a single quote `'` within a single-quoted string, `'"'"'` closes the original string, inserts a double-quoted single quote, then reopens a single-quoted string.

If you're targeting Bash specifically, then you can also use a "C-style"/ANSI string:

```
sh -c $'echo \'"A=x"||"B=y"||"C=z"\''
```

Within `$' '`, a single quote can be inserted using `\'`.

Comment: What bash isn't ansi string supported in?

Comment: @123 I didn't realise that it has been supported for so long - I've edited my answer, thanks.